# i have created recycleview and framelayout(Mapfragment) with sameview , but framelayout always in front even through its gone

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-framelayout, mapfragment

I have added my code which contains `Framelayout` with mapview dynamic creation and `RecyclerView` with another layout, I am using this as a `Fragment` in `ViewPager` fragmentstate adapter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">  
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_above="@+id/custom_progress1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />    
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dear Friend you have added parent layout as relative layout. Use Linear Layout instead of using relative layout. And also use weight in child layouts.So that you can view your screen exactly as you wanted.

Comment: i have changed but still same responce,Initially swiping is working fine,Once mapview is selected and again back to listview then swipe is dead, then once i have changed page using pagestrip of viewpager then its working fine.

Comment: Consider using a more precise title for your question instead of a complete sentence.

Comment: Have you done any changes in your java code?. If it is as it is. It will work properly. Otherwise you might have done some changes.

Comment: do i need to remove fragment while return into listview?

Comment: I am not getting where you are stuck. But I think you should understand the code and then go with your concept.

Comment: How you want to show UI i mean mapview should be below list item or ??

Comment: nope,I have viewpager with pagestrip,
on top of pagestrip i have option to show map/list
initially i am showing list,its working fine,Once the map is viewed then not able to swipe from list,

am trying to change view from recycleview into framelayout then again framelayout from recycleview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to have single parent layout which helps in faster UI rendering. You can use something like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="5dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have more views like loading spinner and all so i need to do with two parent no other way